# Add contact with custom phone number label

Tags: android

I'd like the ability to add a contact to the user's contacts with a contact name (easy enough), a phone number, but also a custom label for that phone number as supported in ICS.  For example, I might like to add "John Doe" with the phone number "xxx-xxx-xxxx" as custom type "Blackberry".  Is this granularity possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with an Intent as seen below. (Bonus: You don't have to ask for read/write contacts permissions!) The specific fields you're interested in are ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE and ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE

```
private void addContact(Activity activity)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "John Smith");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "john@example.com");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "555-555-5555");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, "Blackberry");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE, 555-444-3333);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE, "School Phone");
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
}
```

Comment: The following two lines from your code do not work fine:
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE, 555-444-3333); intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE, "School Phone");
The resulting intent does not contain the mentioned phone number and type on Nexus 6 (Android N).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.
It is Custom add multiple record inside the one contact.

**It's very easy for save contact detail application to default phone contact book.**

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

        ContentValues row2 = new ContentValues();
        row2.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        row2.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_CUSTOM);
        row2.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL, "Green Bot");
        row2.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, "android@android.com");
        data.add(row2);

        ContentValues row3 = new ContentValues();
        row3.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        row3.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
        row3.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, "Arpit");
        row3.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "Aaa@android.com");
        data.add(row3);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Jiks");
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "john@example.com");
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "555-555-5555");
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
        startActivity(intent);
```